# Display Android int value in textview

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have a piece of code which I am having a bit of trouble working with. The code essentially gets the number of rows unread and returns the number. This code however is the sole reason my app is crashing once the function is called by the app. Kindly assist.

```
public int dbMsgSyncCount(){
int count = 0;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM " + MESSAGES_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + MESSAGE_STATUS
        + " = no", null);
count = cursor.getCount();
db.close();
return count;
}
```

In my activity I have :

```
TextView tr = (TextView) R.id.title;
int pt =db.dbMsgSyncCount();
tr.setText(pt);
```

Comment: Please add your error log to your question. That said, replace `tr.setText(pt)` with `tr.setText(String.valueOf(pt))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you send an int to the `setText()`method, the method  will try to find a String resource that matches that int and crashes. So the solution is call `tr.setText(String.valueOf(pt))`

```
TextView tr = (TextView) R.id.title;
int pt =db.dbMsgSyncCount();
tr.setText(String.valueOf(pt));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your `int` to an `Integer` and then you can call `toString()`

```
TextView tr = (TextView) R.id.title;
Integer pt = new Integer(db.dbMsgSyncCount());
tr.setText(pt.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way:

```js
TextView tr = (TextView) R.id.title;
int pt = db.dbMsgSyncCount();
tr.setText(pt + "");
```